# While saving Excel sheet as html, how to add descriptive tags such as "title"?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, html

I am in the middle of a project to publish in the internet a table (with some content the nature of which is not important here) in form of a simple html page.

The table is derived from an Excel sheet via saving the sheet as html, then sending the html (plus a folder of accompanying picture and style files) onto the server.

Problem: the html created by Excel (I use currently Excel 2010) does not have a "title" tag in the head section. I should, however, have such a title tag, for improving the chance this page being found by search engines.

Of course I could add a title tag manually to the output html. However, as this is a complex project with several updates per day in the Excel table, I want this title tag to be there automatically, i.e. from the point where I save the Excel sheet as html (for which, by the way, I made a macro procedure enabling me to publish the latest content by just pressing a button).

How can I make Excel include my desired

```
<title>Something that makes really sense</title>
```

line into the head section of the html?

Answer (score 1):

Excel (as well as LibreOffice) has a Header and Footer that can be defined.

In libreoffice it is Menu:Format > Page > Header  (and Footer) > Edit

As I have no Excel available I can only guess:
It might be in Menu: File > Page format > ... or the corresponding Ribbon entry.

NOW: I would expect the Header content to appear in the HTML, e.g. in  <HEAD>'s <TITLE> subitem

Answer (score 1):

1. Click on Save As, then select Web page on the Save As type box
2. Click on Publish, then click on Change button. You should be able to enter a title